# Execute stored procedure in UPDATE T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have next t-sql code

```
UPDATE
    #f_contr_temp
SET
    sum_percent = (EXEC get_f_contr_credit_delay_pz fct.f_contr, @date_loop, @sum_percent OUTPUT)
FROM
    #f_contr_temp AS fct,
    f_garanty AS fg
WHERE
    fct.f_contr = fg.f_contr
```

Im trying to update sum_percent column but throw an exception what i can't execute procedure in update.
I have no idea, how update my column. Please help.

Comment: If that's a computation you should better convert your stored procedure into a function and then use the function to update the table's column.

Comment: Also as I can see there's no use of inner join with `f_garanty` table as sproc `get_f_contr_credit_delay_pz` is not taking any input from this table..

Comment: @Deepshikha. The inner join can also be filtering. Only update values in fct that are present in fg. But I agree with converting this to a function.

Answer (score 0):

Use a temporary table to store result of your S.P. as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (percentage decimal(18,9))

INSERT INTO #temp
(EXEC get_f_contr_credit_delay_pz fct.f_contr, @date_loop, @sum_percent OUTPUT)

UPDATE
    #f_contr_temp
SET
    sum_percent = (select top 1 percentage from #temp)
FROM
    #f_contr_temp AS fct,
    f_garanty AS fg
WHERE
    fct.f_contr = fg.f_contr
```

I suppose your S.P. return values, so I use TOP 1 command to get only the first.

**Pay attention** `fct.f_contr`, which is its source? In this way the query is not correct.

Comment: Your statement will fail.

Comment: @samyi: If you write that, please add your consideration, so I can correct my answer, so our friends can be read a valid answer. For  further example: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/23/sql-server-insert-values-of-stored-procedure-in-table-use-table-valued-function/

Comment: `fct.f_contr` in your execution statement is not valid... and there's no need for a temp table and "top 1" when you can use the output parameter.. in other words, your answer is simply incorrect. ;)

Comment: Ok, but I've copied from OP statement. I don't know how replace that element